# Yet another XSL transformation situation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a little annoying problem.

I have this XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<info>line1<br/>line2<br/>line3<br/>line4<br/>line5</info>
```

....transformed by this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="info">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The HTML output is:

```
line1line2line3line4line5
```

...but I would like it to be:

```
line1<br>
line2<br>
line3<br>
line4<br>
line5<br>
```

....and I cannot remove the `<br/>` from the XML-file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the raw text of the transformation output?  (you mention the HTML output is "line1line2line3line4line5" but what is the raw output?)

Comment: Technically `<br>` is wrong - it should be `<br />`. (*Please* pay attention to how your post looks in the preview! Large parts were obfuscated by the bad code formatting.)

Comment: `<br>` is just something I had to add to make it show up vertically on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy those `br` elements then use

```
<xsl:for-each select="info">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: @PaulBergström:  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.